# Как передать данные в модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Есть таблица с данными, нужно реализовать редактирование записей в модальном окне, как передать данные конкретной записи в модальное окно в инпуты ?
[image: таблица с записями]

Модальное окно

[image: Модальное окно]

Как заполнить его данными конкретной записи из таблицы ?

Я пробовал через GET параметр передавать ID записи, потом через него выполнять запрос с условием выбранного ID, если кнопка нажата, затем вставлять полученные данные в модальное окно, но у меня оно закрывается сразу же после открытия.

код таблицы:

```
<table class="table table-sm  table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size: 12px;">
    <thead class="table-secondary">
        <tr>
            <th>№</th>
            <th>ПОДРАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ</th>
            <th>ТИП ТЕХНИКИ</th>
            <th>ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬ</th>
            <th>МОДЕЛЬ</th>
            <th>СЕРИЙНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
            <th>ИНВЕНТАРНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
            <th>ДАТА ВВОДА В ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИЮ</th>
            <th>ДЕЙСТВИЯ</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-light">
        <?php if (!empty ($ressprav)){ foreach ($ressprav as $resspr){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50px"><?php  echo $resspr->id_spravtech; ?></td>
                <td><?php  echo $resspr->name_subdivision; ?></td>
                <td><?php  echo $resspr->type; ?></td>
                <td><?php  echo $resspr->manufacture; ?></td>
                <td><?php  echo $resspr->model; ?></td>
                <td><?php  echo $resspr->serial_number; ?></td>
                <td><?php  echo $resspr->inventary_number; ?></td>
                <td><?php  echo $resspr->date; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="bttnaction">
                        <div class="bttnactiongroup">
                            <a  href="?update_id=<?php  echo $resspr->id_spravtech; ?>">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updatetech">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </button>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash" ></i>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }?>
            <?php }else{?>
            <tr><td colspan=9>В БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ НЕТ ЗАПИСЕЙ</td></tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

модальное окно:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updatetech" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Редактирование техники &nbsp</h5><h5 class="modal-title text-danger" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Подразделение</span>
                        <input value="<?php echo $resselecttechupdate[0]->name_subdivision?>" required name="manufacture" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Тип техники</span>
                        <input value="<?php echo $resselecttechupdate[0]->type?>" required name="manufacture" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Производитель</span>
                        <input value="<?php echo $resselecttechupdate[0]->manufacture?>" required name="manufacture" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Модель</span>
                        <input value="<?php echo $resselecttechupdate[0]->model?>" required name="model" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Серийный номер</span>
                        <input value="<?php echo $resselecttechupdate[0]->serial_number?>" required name="serialnumber" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Инвентарный номер</span>
                        <input value="<?php echo $resselecttechupdate[0]->inventary_number?>" required name="inventarynumber" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Дата ввода в эксплуатацию</span>
                        <input value="<?php echo $resselecttechupdate[0]->date?>" required name="date" type="date" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button name="updatetech" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном примере покажу как считать данные (одним из способов) из таблицы на js.
Алгоритм следующий:

1. Вешаем событие на нашу таблицу
2. Определяем на какую кнопку кликнули
3. Ищем строку которую кликнули (tr). Получаем из неё данные (td, кроме последнего, так как там наши кнопки и они не нужны)
4. Записываем данные в объект (в качестве ключей я взял thead)
5. Вызываем модальное окно.

Домашнее задание:
Вывести объект который приходит в `showModal` в модальное окно. Суть та же как и при работе с таблицей. Ищете тег `form` в окне, определяете инпуты, далее подставляете в нужные места. В конце записи данных в инпут, вызовите в `bootstrap` js функцию: показать модальное окно.

Изменения кода при написании примера:
У таблицы добавлен id

убран тег `a` в которую обёрнута кнопка

добавлен `data` атрибут у кнопок `type`

`data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updatetech"` данные атрибуты не будут нужны , так как показ окна будет осуществляться принудительно в определённый момент.

```js
const table = document.getElementById('table-info');

table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return;
  const head = table.tHead.rows[0].cells
  const tr = e.target.closest('tr');
  
  if (e.target.dataset.type == 'edit') editRow(head, tr);
  if (e.target.dataset.type == 'delete') deleteRow(tr);
});

function editRow(head, tr) {
  const current = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.cells.length - 1; i++) {
    current[head[i].innerText] = tr.cells[i].innerText
  }
  showModal(current)
}

function deleteRow(tr) {
   tr.remove();
}

function showModal(editData) {
  console.log(editData);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-sm  table-bordered table-hover" id="table-info" style="font-size: 12px;">
    <thead class="table-secondary">
        <tr>
            <th>№</th>
            <th>ПОДРАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ</th>
            <th>ТИП ТЕХНИКИ</th>
            <th>ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬ</th>
            <th>МОДЕЛЬ</th>
            <th>СЕРИЙНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
            <th>ИНВЕНТАРНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
            <th>ДАТА ВВОДА В ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИЮ</th>
            <th>ДЕЙСТВИЯ</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-light">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50px">1</td>
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>car</td>
                <td>bar</td>
                <td>kia</td>
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>12345</td>
                <td>2022-01-01</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="bttnaction">
                        <div class="bttnactiongroup">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updatetech" data-type="edit">
                                edit
                            </button>
                            <a href="#">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-type="delete">
                                    delete
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вижу что данные выдергивает, но как вставить их в модальное окно в форму я не имею ни малейшего представления, с JS совсем не работал(